# I'm not Getting any number of calls in my React Test using React Testing Library

Tags: javascript, reactjs, testing, jestjs, react-testing-library

I mocked my login component using react testing library, did the necessary "getBy's" and used fireEvent to submit or click on the submit button. I rendered the component with an onSubmit function but it still doesn't get called.

```
it("Calls onSubmit with username and Password when submitted", () => {
   const onSubmit = jest.fn();
   const { getByTestId, getByText } = render(
      <MemoryRouter>
           <Login onSubmit = {onSubmit} />
      </MemoryRouter>
      );
      const button = getByText("Login");
      const email = getByTestId("email");
      const password = getByTestId("password");
      const form = getByTestId("form-element");

    fireEvent.change(email, { target: { value: "Tolulope@gmail.com" } });
    fireEvent.change(password, { target: { value: "YummyPizza" } });
    fireEvent.click(button);

   expect(onSubmit).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(1);
   expect(onSubmit).toHaveBeenCalledWith({
      email: email.value,
      password: password.value,
});

 });
```

I tried but fireEvent.submit and fireEvent.click on the form and button respectively but both seem not to trigger the function.

Here is the setup for my login component.

```
 <form data-testid="form-element" style={{width: "360px"}}>
    <Input data-testid= "email"    onChange={handleChange} value={email}   name='email' type='text' label='Email Address' icon = 'at' required/>
    <Input data-testid= "password"    onChange={handleChange} value={password} name='password' type='password' label='Password' icon = 'lock' required/>

    <ButtonAuth  className='text-xl text-white uppercase cursor-pointer  mt-1 block w-full h-12 outline-none border-none bg-green-500 mt-3' value='Login' type="submit" onSubmit={onSubmit} disabled={!enabled} />

</form>
```

The Input and Button are both components but reusable input and button tags.

Answer (score 1):

You have to fire the submit event on a form.

```
it("Calls onSubmit with username and Password when submitted", () => {
  const onSubmit = jest.fn();
  const { getByTestId } = render(
    <MemoryRouter>
      <Login onSubmit={onSubmit} />
    </MemoryRouter>
  );

  const form = getByTestId("form-element");

  expect(onSubmit).not.toHaveBeenCalled();

  fireEvent.submit(form, {
    target: {
      values: {
        email: "Tolulope@gmail.com",
        password: "YummyPizza",
      },
    },
  });

  expect(onSubmit).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(1);
  expect(onSubmit).toHaveBeenCalledWith({
    email: "Tolulope@gmail.com",
    password: "YummyPizza",
  });
});
```

Comment: Thanks for the help, I did this earlier, still wasn't working

Comment: @TOLULOPEADETULA The above is how I test my forms, but interestingly enough, kentcdodds [here](https://github.com/testing-library/react-testing-library/issues/54) suggests firing a click event on the submit button. Do you mind updating and sharing a minimal example of the form component you're trying to test so we've a better idea what you're working with?

Comment: I've edited the question to add the form. I'll check the blog post now

Comment: @TOLULOPEADETULA Bruh, the `onSubmit` callback goes on the form, not the button.

Comment: My bad, It was initially there, it was in my process of debugging why it wasn't working, I moved down to the button.

Comment: If you want, you can keep it in the button but change to the `onClick` event. Be sure to change the type of the button from 'submit' to 'button' though so it doesn't submit the form normally. Otherwise, move it back up on the form element.